# Create Entity with signalStore and rxMethod

Tags: angular, signals, ngrx, store, angular17

I have an error message that I understand, but I don't know how to resolve it. The 'add' call works without HTTP and 'rxMethod.' However, this method cannot be loaded outside of the constructor. What am I doing wrong?

```
addEntity: (entityToPush: entity) => {
          return rxMethod(pipe(
            tap(() => patchState(entityStore, {isLoading: true})),
            switchMap(() => entityHttpService.createEntity(entityToPush).pipe(
              tapResponse({
                next: (entityToPush) => patchState(entityStore, {entities: [...entityStore.entities(), entityToPush]}),
                error: console.error,
                finalize: () => patchState(entityStore, {isLoading: false})
              })
            ))
          ));
```

error: rxMethod() can only be used within an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with

Answer (score 1):

You are utilizing the method wrong. It should be:

```
addEntity: rxMethod<entity>(pipe(
 // ...       
));
```

Follow this:

1. https://github.com/ngrx/platform/discussions/3796#rxmethod
2. https://www.angulararchitects.io/blog/the-new-ngrx-signal-store-for-angular-2-1-flavors/
3. https://ngrx.io/guide/signals/signal-store